# how combine two variables into a new variable

Tags: less

declare two variables like maps (only variable, not maps). and combine them to a new variable.

Except.

```
@a: { @x: 1;}
@b: { @x: 2; @y: 3}

.combine(@m, @n) {
  @c: // some codes here. make @m and @n combine to @c ;
}

.combine(@a, @b);

// result
// @c[@x] = 2
// @c[@y] = 3
```